# I can not import something into my module (mjs-file)

Tags: javascript, module, syntax-error

I have here a Chrome Extension and can not import anything to my main (index.mjs) script into it.

index.mjs File:

```
import Browser from "webextension-polyfill"; 

const port = Browser.runtime.connect();
```

index.html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="input-el" type="text">
        <button id="submit-btn"> submit </button>
    </div>
    <div id="content-El"></div>
    
    <script src="index.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module [index.mjs:1]

I tried to a lot of things.

- type="module" in my html
- rename file ending to mjs & js

Comment: `webextension-polyfill` is virtual path. Only npm can understand this. You need to find real path.
Real this blog [3 ways to add npm package in chrome extension](https://dev.to/anilkumarum/3-ways-to-add-npm-package-in-chrome-extension-3e3b)

Comment: lol okay thank you. And which one is the real path for webextension-polyfill @Anilkumar? Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/gRhcSTeQDu35

Comment: I have tried: import Browser from "./node_modules/webextension-polyfill/dist/browser-polyfill.js";  and it still does give me the same error, screenshot: https://prnt.sc/gvVzmqpeZFaT

Comment: remove first dot char. import Browser from "/node_modules/webextension-polyfill/dist/browser-polyfill.js";

Comment: Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/Qlh89BLsiUv4 | still not working

Comment: I don't know where the problem is, do you think something else could cause the problem? Maybe I should consider something because it is a chrome extension ? :/

Comment: Is there a way to use the virtual path ?

Comment: `<script type="module" src="/node_modules/webextension-polyfill/dist/browser-polyfill.js">
</script>`

Comment: Oh thanks it works now, do you know how can I implement: const port = Browser.runtime.connect(); in a way that my index.mjs file has access to it ^^

Comment: Because in that file I am listening to the port. So need to have access to it even though my script is in the html. Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/q1JWt1YO6evC